# Printing Teradata SQL results to command line - Python

Tags: python, teradata

I have this script that executes correctly, but I'd like to print the results of the SQL script to the screen.  What needs to be added?

Thanks

```
import teradata
import sys
import pwd

def main():

    udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="DataWarehouseConnectionTest", version="1.0", logConsole=True)

    mConn = udaExec.connect(method="odbc",dsn="test",username=pwd.username,password=pwd.password)

    mConn.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB.Test')

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to print the result of the query by looping on the expression directly :

```
for line in mConn.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB.Test'):
    print(line)
```

Or in your case:

```
res = mConn.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB.Test')
if res:
    print(res[0])
```

Comment: you can check this doc too : https://developer.teradata.com/tools/reference/teradata-python-module